# Laravel + bootstrap (how to change pages)

Tags: php, laravel

i need some help with some changes on a web site for SEO . 
i need to:

1. change some h1 tags to h2
2. set up a 404 page to a certain adress
3. set up 301 redirect instead of 302. 
   how can i archieve that ?

sorry for noobish questions, i've never worked with PHP

Comment: You'll likely have to find the `<h1>` tags in `resources/views` somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please don't put the relevant technologies in the question, instead rely on the tags! Stack overflow can take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Global find and replace regex `<(/?)h1>` to `<$1h2>` (NetBeans can do this)
2. If the route does not exist Laravel will return the 404 page by default. You can force a route to error by doing:

   ```
   Route::get("/errorroute",function () {
       abort(404,"Found but not really");
   });
   ```
3. When you generate a redirect using `redirect($url)` you can pass a 2nd parameter e.g. `redirect($url,301)` or `redirect(null,301)->back()`

If you set up a redirect in your webserver you can specify the redirect code there as well (how depends on the webserver).